# Make all nested lists equal to the length to the smallest(minimum length'ed) list in R

Tags: r, list, lapply, nested-lists

I have a question that is different from padding nested lists with NA values in R. Suppose I have a nested list with 3 lists:

```
mylist <- list(
  A = as.data.frame(matrix(1:9, ncol=3, byrow=TRUE, dimnames=list(1:3, letters[1:3]))),
  B = as.data.frame(matrix(10:21, ncol=3, byrow=TRUE, dimnames=list(1:4, letters[1:3]))),
  C = as.data.frame(matrix(22:36, ncol=3, byrow=TRUE, dimnames=list(1:5, letters[1:3])))
)

$A 
  a b c 
1 1 2 3 
2 4 5 6 
3 7 8 9


$B 
  a  b  c 
1 10 11 12 
2 13 14 15 
3 16 17 18 
4 19 20 21

$C 
  a  b  c 
1 22 23 24 
2 25 26 27 
3 28 28 30 
4 31 32 33 
5 34 35 36
```

How do I write the codes in **R** that gives me an **output** like this.

```
$A 
  a b c 
1 1 2 3 
2 4 5 6 
3 7 8 9


$B 
  a  b  c 
1 10 11 12 
2 13 14 15 
3 16 17 18 


$C 
  a  b  c 
1 22 23 24 
2 25 26 27 
3 28 28 30
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the smallest number of rows with

```
min(sapply(mylist, nrow))
```

and then you can pass that into a function like `head()` to only keep that many rows per data.frame. You can do that all in one step with

```
lapply(mylist, head, min(sapply(mylist, nrow)))
```